# Django Employee Profile Page Customization

Tags: python, html, django

I am new to Django as well as Python.  I am trying to build a Employee management System using django framework. 
Till now I was able to build models and show the models in admin module. Now I want to show user a user profile and able to update their details.
I am still in starting phase of the project. What I want to do is, I want show the profile page in the below format i.e similar to admin page look.[image: admin Page look]

But till now I was able to get like below

[image: Profile page look]
Is it possible to make profile page of each employee look just like admin page look? which has collapsible options as well

Comment: Of course it's possible if you have the HTML/CSS.

Comment: The main problem I am facing here is I am unable to bring more than one form in the profile page. Any suggestion for this? I did research on this but didn't get or rather understood how to apply to my project.

Comment: I don't think those are multiple forms in the admin page. It's just a single form, just grouped in different categories.

Comment: @Bibhas They are different models but related using a foreign Key. When I say different models I have 4 differents tables, i.e Employee, Dept, Current Address, Permanet Adrress.  Now What I am trying to do is in the profile page bring all these for the logged in employee.  Anyway Thanks a lot for your input. I think I need to further research on this

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write your views as well as create you template folder with the relevant template tag.

I believe that is what will get you what you want. 
The models you create shows the database columns and rows you want Django to create.
Please check the link below assuming you are using Django 1.6:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 0):

The collapsible part of Django admin, is made with JavaScript (jQuery) & CSS.
If you want your page to be dynamic, use JavaScript.
If you want to make it more beautiful, use CSS.